# Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf", The system cannot find the file specified in windows

Tags: java, windows, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed wkhtmltopdf and set bin path of wkhtmltopdf in environment variable path and I have also tried to change location of wkhtmltopdf to other system folder

```
WkHtmlToPdf pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf("C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe");
```

above line is not working in windows and getting below exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:493) ~[?:?]
        at com.ztomic.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf.convert(WkHtmlToPdf.java:84) ~[wkhtmltopdf-java-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at com.ztomic.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf.getPdfBytes(WkHtmlToPdf.java:77) ~[wkhtmltopdf-java-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at com.giddh.api.utils.Utility.generatePdfByWkHtmlToPdf(Utility.java:2838) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.giddh.api.services.util.InvoiceUtilService.convertInvoiceTemplateFromHtmlToPdf(InvoiceUtilService.java:1874) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.giddh.api.services.util.InvoiceUtilService.convertInvoiceTemplateAsHtmlV4(InvoiceUtilService.java:1819) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.giddh.api.services.util.InvoiceUtilService.createInvoiceTemplateV2(InvoiceUtilService.java:521) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.giddh.api.services.util.InvoiceUtilService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f08313eb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) [spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.giddh.api.services.util.InvoiceUtilService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b67e9a51.createInvoiceTemplateV2(<generated>) [classes/:?]
        at com.giddh.api.services.enter code hereutil.InvoiceUtilService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f08313eb.invoke(<generated>) [classes`enter code here`/:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: This may sound dumb, but is it saved at that exact path?

Comment: Is your program files folder really written `ProgramFiles`? Usually it has a space in between

Comment: yes it has space between in programFiles and I have also set bin path of wkhtmltopdf in environment variable path

Comment: Well, then your path is wrong if you've written `ProgramFiles` instead of `Program Files`

Comment: I had change the path but still getting same error

Comment: I also tried to change location of wkhtmltopdf to other system folder but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `ProcessBuilder.start()` I see the following code

```java
            // It's much easier for us to create a high-quality error
            // message than the low-level C code which found the problem.
            throw new IOException(
                "Cannot run program \"" + prog + "\""
                + (dir == null ? "" : " (in directory \"" + dir + "\")")
                + exceptionInfo,
                cause);
```

As it comes from the comment the problem is not necessarily about the wrong path.
Can you debug the app to see what is the message of `cause`? Maybe the root cause has something to do with permissions. What if target `exe` file is put on another drive?